# POST Request Issue in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working with NodeJS and I'm working on letting users upload files. Right now though I'm having a lot of problem even trying to get a simple POST request.

Over in my index.ejs file I have some code that creates a form and then sends a post request:

```
<div id="uploaddiv">Upload things here<br>
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="text" name="title"><br>
<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</div>
```

Then in server.js, I have code that handles the uploading.

```
var server = express.createServer();
//bunch of stuff left out
server.get('/upload', function(req, res) {
console.log("uploading!");
if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    res.write('lol');
}
});
```

My problem is that navigating directly to localhost/upload will console.log properly, but clicking on the button gives me the error "Cannot POST /upload".

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`server.get` means handle an HTTP GET.  You want `server.post`.  FYI the "Cannot XXX /uri" error is what express responds with when no active route matches the request and no 404 error handler has been configured.

Comment: Oh, I feel incredibly dumb now. I thought it was going to be something really stupid, but not something of this magnitude. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

By using `server.get()`, you're instructing that route to only respond to GET requests, but the form is obviously a POST.

You should use `server.post()`.

You can also use `server.any()` if you want to it respond to both GET and POST (and every other HTTP verb as well).

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use Felix Geisendörfer's [node-formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) to upload files.

```
var express     = require('express'),
    app     = express.createServer(),
    util        = require('util'),
    formidable  = require('formidable');

app.get('/upload', function (req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>');
});

app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = '.';
    form.keepExtensions = true;

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('received upload:\n\n');
        res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
    return;
});

app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

It is just a simple as this to do file uploading thanks to node-formidable.